# Convert Tcl array to C++ map in SWIG

Tags: c, arrays, loops, tcl

I'm looking for a way to iterate over Tcl array, specified by it's name in C code.
The problem for which this iteration is needed is a SWIG typemap to convert Tcl array to C++ map. The code should look like this:

```
%typemap(tcl8, in) map<int,int> * (map<int,int> dltmp) {
  map<int,int> *cMap = new map<int,int>;
  int key, value;
  pair<int,int> mapEnt;

  // somehow iterate over Tcl array specified by it's name in $source
  // to get key and value
  {
    mapEnt.first = key;
    mapEnt.second = value;
    cMap.insert(mapEnt);
  }

  $target = cMap;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for an implementation of `startsearch` and `nextelement` in C or a way to interface code in Tcl and C, using the latter to call those functions? Please clarify and perhaps provide a more elaborate _use-case_, which would ease the process of understanding your problem and improve the probability of it being answered.

Comment: There isn't such a way at the C level. Even at the internal API level, there's no such API; the iterators work right at the implementation level and they're messy.